# Generating classes in eclipse Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an existing project and I have imported it to a maven project in Eclipse Juno.

The classes are to be generated into the folder **target->classes** by default settings

But i see the java files in there and not the class files. Sounds weird to me. I tried to build the project, try creating new project. Doesn't seem to work. If its a normal project, it does generate the classes.

Anyone faced this problem before? Your inputs on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Reema

Comment: you're not seeing the files in Eclipse directly? Or you can't see your files in your filesystem (if you go directly to check that directory) ?

Comment: Did you take a look at it outside of eclipse?

Comment: Of course, eclipse is not showing the folder itself. Guess its hidden. But the file system is showing java files and not class files

Comment: well, if the maven project is set to generate the classes elsewhere, then it's probably one of the causes why you can't see the class files. Can you look in the pom.xml to see if it does actually have som e sort of custom place to generate the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that I have added java files under the  src/main/resources directory and not the  src/main/java directory. Moving the files to java directory solved the issue.

Thanks all for the inputs.